# How to actually submit my app to Ubuntu app showdown?

Tags: application-development

How to actually submit app to Ubuntu app showdown? I wanted to know how to make my submitted app eligible for app showdown.

I know that I have to create a PPA at Launchpad and submit my app to Ubuntu software center. But how will they come to know that it is for Ubuntu app show down? Can you tell me step by step?

Answer (score 3):

- The first thing we need do is package your application. Quickly makes packaging really easy. See the [guide for Quickly](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Quickly). You need just one command to package using Quickly.
- Run `quickly submitubuntu` to create your package and upload it to a PPA in Launchpad. If you have any issues, check out the [troubleshooting guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160774/how-to-troubleshoot-quickly-packaging-failures).
- Then you need to submit to Ubuntu Software Center. Go to [My Apps portal](https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/). You will need an account. If you don't have, create one. It's free. Then you will need to create a txt file like this:

  - http://developer.ubuntu.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Ubuntu-App-Showdown-Participation-Details.txt

  Then submit it to your application field. Then in the comment field later, you will have to submit your PPA location.

This is explained in **Step 4** on the main [Ubuntu App Showdown page.](http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown/)