# How to troubleshoot Quickly packaging failures

Tags: 12.04, application-development, quickly, packaging

I have created a Quickly app and I'm trying to create a package for distributing it through the Software Center.

However, whenever I try one of the Quickly packaging commands (`package`, `share`, `release` or `submitubuntu`), it fails without telling me exactly why.

How can I troubleshoot the packaging failure so I can either investigate it or ask for help about it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `package` command to build a local package, specifying the `--verbose` option. This will give you the full output of the underlying tools Quickly invokes to create your package. Run it as such on your project folder:

```
quickly package --verbose
```

Another command that might help:

```
python setup.py build
```

### Common issues

- [Modules with syntax errors will cause the package build to fail](https://askubuntu.com/a/153194/9781)
- The `share`, `release` and `submitubuntu` commands require a properly set up [Launchpad account](https://help.launchpad.net/YourAccount/NewAccount), with an [SSH key](https://help.launchpad.net/YourAccount/CreatingAnSSHKeyPair) and a [PPA](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/)
- You'll need a [GPG key](https://help.launchpad.net/YourAccount/ImportingYourPGPKey) to sign your package
- If you don't specify a PPA name as a parameter to the packaging command, or if you haven't set it with the `quickly configure ppa`, Quickly will assume it is called `ppa`. So if your PPA is named differently, make sure to tell it to Quickly in either of the two ways above. [Learn more about how Quickly gets the PPA name](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96472/where-does-quickly-get-the-ppa-name-from).

### Non-Quickly build

The Quickly packaging commands overwrite the packaging control files every time they are run. In some occasions, and if you know what you are doing, you might want or need to modify them without Quickly overwriting them. In those cases you can:

1. Do the required changes to the packaging control files
2. Run `debuild -S` in your source tree to build a local source package
3. Run `dput ppa:yourusername/ppa ../projectname_*_source.changes` to upload the local source package to your remote PPA in Launchpad
4. Check whether [your PPA](https://launchpad.net/people/+me/+archive) is building the package or wait for the e-mail from Launchpad to indicate success or failure