# I cant push my app to ppa with quickly submitubuntu command

Tags: quickly, application-submission

I have the launchpad the ppa and the project configured but when I try to 
`quickly submitubuntu` it aborts. I tried to create the Debian package with `quickly package --extras` and it worked and with the 'quickly package' it worked too, I don't understand...

This is my submission to the app showdown...

The error:

```
glink@glink:~/mydev/SRC/src-install$ quickly submitubuntu 
Obter definições do Launchpad
bzr: ERROR: The user fernandofreamunde has not registered any SSH keys with Launchpad.
See <https://launchpad.net/people/+me>
Launchpad connection is ok
.............Ubuntu packaging created in debian/
...ERROR: quickly can't release: can't push to launchpad.
ERRO: O comando submitubuntu falhou
A abortar
glink@glink:~/mydev/SRC/src-install$
```

Comment: For future reference, this would have helped debugging: http://askubuntu.com/questions/160774/how-to-troubleshoot-quickly-packaging-failures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a SSH key and upload it into Launchpad.

Instructions:

Step 1: Install OpenSSH. On Ubuntu, you can install OpenSSH by opening your terminal and typing:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-client
```

Step 2: Once OpenSSH is installed, stay in the terminal and type:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Step 3: When prompted, press Enter to accept the default file name for your key.

Step 4: Next, enter then confirm a password to protect your SSH key. Your key pair is stored in ~/.ssh/ as id_rsa.pub (public key) and id_rsa (private key)

Now you need to upload the public portion of your SSH key to Launchpad.

```
Source: Launchpad - https://help.launchpad.net/YourAccount/CreatingAnSSHKeyPair
```

Comment: thank you so much that worked, now im nervous to see the results :) because some one told me that i was already late although the countdown is still active :/

Comment: Down to the last minute! Good job for getting something submitted!

Comment: thanks :) 
now in the launchpad it don't build, apparently it is a quickly bug trying the proposed fix for it :)