# Quickly: share, release and submitubuntu not working anymore

Tags: application-development, python, quickly

I have the problem that after applying the changes suggested from the ARB (modifying some  `debian/*` and such files) the commands `quickly {share,release,submitubuntu}` oddly stopped working for me.

However, `quickly {package,run}` still works just fine.

You can find my program with the latest source code here: https://launchpad.net/uberwriter

```
wolf@wolf-laptop:~/Programme/uberwriter$ quickly release
Get Launchpad Settings
Launchpad connection is ok
............An error has occurred when creating debian packaging
ERROR: can't create or update ubuntu package
ERROR: release command failed
Aborting
```

I would be really happy about any suggestions how to fix that, because I really liked the quickly workflow, which was (up to now) incredible painless.

-wolfv

Comment: Looks like a direct duplicate to me: See [I cant push my app to ppa with quickly submitubuntu command](http://askubuntu.com/questions/161669/i-cant-push-my-app-to-ppa-with-quickly-submitubuntu-command). But you've already solved it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there was a wrong name+email in my changelog, so I changed that. Quickly didn't work, but I was able to build the package with `debuild -S` and then `dput` it to my ppa.

Sorry for asking, but maybe it'll help someone in the future.

I also used `export DEBFULLNAME="..."` and `export DEBEMAIL="..."`

Comment: For future reference, this would have helped debugging: http://askubuntu.com/questions/160774/how-to-troubleshoot-quickly-packaging-failures and here is a quick guide on how to apply the ARB's fixes to your app: http://askubuntu.com/questions/163096/how-do-i-apply-the-fixes-suggested-from-the-app-review-board-to-my-app