# "Quickly package" command failed without the relevant error message

Tags: application-development, quickly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to troubleshoot Quickly packaging failures](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160774/how-to-troubleshoot-quickly-packaging-failures)

When I do `quickly run`, my app runs perfectly but when I use `quickly package` it just aborts. It says there was an error but doesn't show the error message.

```
$ quickly run
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py:391: Warning: g_object_set_property: construct property "type" for object `Window' can't be set after construction
 Gtk.Window.__init__(self, type=type, **kwds)

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py:391: Warning: g_object_set_property: construct property "type" for object `MybrowserWindow' can't be set after construction
  Gtk.Window.__init__(self, type=type, **kwds)
$ quickly package
........Ubuntu packaging created in debian/

............ An error occurred while creating the package.
ERROR: The command failed package
aborting
```

Comment: Try running it with --verbose, as described here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/160774/how-to-troubleshoot-quickly-packaging-failures